# randomForestOOB Error Rate Diverging with > nTrees

Tags: r, classification, random-forest

I am in a preliminary stage right now with classifying churned customers and have an interesting oob error rate chart that I would really like to get a better understanding of from someone more knowledgable.

**The Data:**

11 features for prediction. Of those, 5 are factors varying from 3-24 levels and 6 integer/numerical.

4,981 observations.

34% OOB error rate (likely need more important features to feed model)
Variables at each split: 3

**The R code:**

```r
rf_model <- randomForest(training_rf$churn_indicator_30~.,data=training_rf,proximity=TRUE,importance=TRUE,ntree=500)
```

```r
oob.error.data <- data.frame(
  Trees=rep(1:nrow(rf_model$err.rate),times=3),
  Type=rep(c("OOB","Churn","Not Churn"),each=nrow(rf_model$err.rate)),
  Error=c(rf_model$err.rate[,"OOB"],
  rf_model$err.rate[,"Churn"],
  rf_model$err.rate[,"Not Churn"]))

ggplot(data=oob.error.data,aes(x=Trees,y=Error)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=Type))
```

[image: oob error rate plot]

**The Questions:**

What would make such a strong divergence between "Not Churn" and "Churn"? "Not Churn" decreases while "Churn" increases.

Why is "Churn" increasing in error rate as more trees are built (which is, of course, not the way a textbook example would ever depict it)?

Any thoughts on where the issue, if any, could reside?

Comment: It seems that your model is better at predicting Not Chum at the expense of Chum. Do you have an imbalanced data set?

Comment: You are absolutely right. The logistic regression and random forest both had high specificity and low sensitivity. Should I be concerned? The data set Churn/Not Churn distribution is 65/35 in favor of not churn.

Comment: That is cause for concern. It looks like the model is predicting most cases as belonging to the majority class, which is not uncommon in such scenarios. Do a simple search on this site for "imbalanced data sets" and why accuracy is not the best measure in this case.

Comment: I think its because of imbalance classes. Try SMOTE'ing it to balance the classes and try building it again.